# How to concat a calculation and use leading '0' in a view

Tags: sql-server, concatenation, leading-zero

I have a question about concat function an dleading '0' in a view.
the code I used in the view is:

```
SELECT DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GETDATE()) + 1 AS Week, YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) % 2000 % 100 AS Year
```

This gives me the correct result.
I would preferably want to have the data that is now spread over 2 columns in the same column.

Also it would be great to have a leading '0' when the result of 'Week' is a sigle digit.

Everything i tried gave an error.

Thanks for your help,

Kind regards

I expect output of (column1: '9') and (column2: '19') to be (column1: '0919')

Comment: That SQL you provided doesn't produce an error for me, what was the SQL you used that errored?

Comment: this code is indeed working, also for me. The problem i have is that i don't have the leading '0' after the calculation of 'Week' is done. And also that i can't get the 2 columns combined in one cell in a view. kind regards

Comment: In regards to the leading zero: numerical datatypes, in SQL Server, don't store leading zeros. If you must display leading zeroes you need to use a `varchar`, or change the formatting property of your value in your presentation layer. Considering your data, I suggest the later, as `0719` is not **after** `0120`, but  `'0719'` is after `'0120'`.

Comment: can i do all this in a view or do i have to create a table to do all this?

Comment: @bregt Van den Bergh suitable answers have been provided below, please validate and mark as accepted, if you feel this answers the quesiton.

Comment: Ok sorry missed that earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert your resiult to varchar, and append 00 to the start of the weeks, then take the right2 of these chars - leaving you the desired output:

```
 SELECT 
 RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR,DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GETDATE()) + 1),2) +''+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) % 2000 % 100) [yourcol]
 FROM YOURTABLE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT 
   DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, GETDATE()) + 1 AS Week,
   YEAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) % 2000 % 100 AS Year,
   RIGHT('00'+CAST(DATEPART(ISO_WEEK, '2/1/2019') + 1 AS VARCHAR(2)),2) + 
      CAST(YEAR('3/1/2019') % 100 AS VARCHAR(2)) AS Combined
```

I replaced  GETDATE with a constant so it is easier to test.